# How to build cconnection between two computers with no public IP

Tags: networking

I'm learning python socket. If I have a server with public IP, my computer and server can connect using TCP easily. But, If two computers in different LAN don't have public ip, how do I connect them ?

Comment: maybe bluetooth?

Comment: I'm developing a network software, so it's necessary to use network programming like TCP to connect them.

Comment: Then host your server in the cloud and use that IP.

Comment: @Enzokie you might mean the 'client to server' connection, I mean the 'client to client' connection. -,-
Or you want to use the server for data forwarding, but I want to directly connect them which is faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is "Use NAT traversal techniques".

Long answer.

The major problems here are:

- When you establish connection you don't really know what IP address to connect.
- NAT doesn't alway works as you may expect (close address translation binding, doesn't accept packets that send from some unexpected addresses etc).

First problem can be solved with so-called STUN server that can give you back your public IP address.

Second problem is more complex and can't be solved in general without server using public IP address. You can look at "[Interactive Connectivity Establishment](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5245)" specification to see example how this problem is solved in VOIP systems.

In short words you can try to use public address got by STUN protocol but if it doesn't work you need to fallback to server with public IP (like TURN server)